# Why operator= and copy constructor are treated differently in virtual inheritance?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, default-constructor

It seems that in virtual inheritance, operator= and copy constructor are treated differently. Consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

class A {
public:
    A(int x) : x(x) {
        std::cout << "A is initialized" << std::endl;
    }

    A(const A& rhs) {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor for A" << std::endl;
    }

    A& operator=(const A& rhs) {
        std::cout << "A::operator=()" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }

    virtual void funcB() = 0;
    virtual void funcC() = 0;
    int x;
};

class B : virtual public A {
public:
    B(int x) {
        std::cout << "B is initialized" << std::endl;
    }
    B(const B& rhs) {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor for B" << std::endl;
    }
    B& operator=(const B& rhs) {
        std::cout << "B::operator=()" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }

    void funcB() override {
        std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
    }
    void funcC() override = 0;
};

class C : public B {
public:
    C(int x) : A(x + 1), B(x) {
        std::cout << "C is initialized" << std::endl;
    }
    void funcC() override {
        std::cout << "C" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    C c(1);
    C c2(c);
    c2 = c;
    std::cout << c.x;
}
```

Here B inherit virtually from A and C inherit from B. The output is:

```
A is initialized
B is initialized
C is initialized
Copy constructor for A
Copy constructor for B
B::operator=()
2
```

We can see that the default copy constructor of C has successfully called the copy constructor for both B and A, which is what I want. But the default operator= did not call operator= of A, which is strange.

A possible explanation to this is that the copy constructor of A is called by B, not C. However, since I have deliberately made B pure virtual, I don't have to initialize A in the copy constructor of B and in fact I did not. So the copy constructor of A is called most likely from C, but I have no proof of it since A will be initialized before B anyway, no matter who calls its constructor.

Comment: This is just how *constructors* work.

Comment: can you make your example with just A and B? Is the C level really needed ?

Comment: @user253751 Since A has not default constructor, any call to A's constructor **must be explicit**. In this example, if B wants to call A's constructor, it must call `A(x)`. Otherwise the compiler won't be able to know which constructor to call and what parameters to use. So I suppose it is not B that calls A's constructor.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom It is needed. I need B to be abstract so that I do not need to initialize A from B (which is legal and exactly what I want, because my final goal is to solve the problem of diamond inheritance, I don't want to elaborate that here as it could be lengthy). Then C is needed because there must be at least one concrete class to showcase my question.

Comment: @Hans because it is virtual, note that the A object is actually part of C, not B. Hence, I presume it is C's default copy constructor that calls both. Still nothing specific to copy constructors as you could write a non-copy constructor that would call both non-copy constructors.

Comment: @user253751 Sorry I misunderstood you before. But my problem is still not resolved. I wonder, since A is part of C, why the default operator= of C does not call operator= of A? Normally if C inherit directly from A, its default operator= will call A's operator=, right?

Comment: @molbdnilo What do you mean by 'not automagically calling a similarly-named inherited function'? Clearly the default operator= calls the opearator= of B. It is definitely not a **normal** member function because normal member function do not have "default" version, right?

Comment: "Why doesn't C++ have feature X"? --- because nobody needs it quite badly enough, so no proposals to add it get written. "But I need it" --- chances are, you think you need it because you have committed a design error early on. Assignment and polymorphic inheritance hierarchies just do not mix well. A class with virtual functions *should have the copy assignment operator disabled by default*. C++ doesn't do that, and it is the real problem.

Comment: @n.m. Now you are saying it, I just found that I never used the copy assignment of C. I implement it just because my teacher used to say copy constructor, destructor and copy assignment should be implemented together, lol. Thanks for the notice.

Comment: This is mostly true, but you can (and probably should) implement the copy assignment this way: `void operator=(const A&) = delete` and be done with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're using compiler generated `operator=` (i.e `C::operator=(const C&)`), which calls `operator=` for all it's ***direct*** base class (and members)

since `A` is not a direct base class of `C`, `A::operator=(const A&)` is not called.

`B` is expected to copy `A` if it want, unlike constructor, you can implement assignment for `B` that *doesn't* change it's `A` (or whatever you want)

---

on the other hand, if `A` is direct base class

```
class C : public B , virtual public A { ... }
```

then the compiler generated `operator=` *would* call `A`'s assignment operator (and [it's unspecific whether `A` is assigned multiple times](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class#copy.assign-example-3))

Comment: I see. But still I feel a little uncomfortable about this. If there is a diamond inheritance A -> B, C -> D and the operator= of both B and C calls that of A, will this means that when I call operator= of D,  A's operator= will be called twice? I thinks such behavior is not tolerable.

Comment: @Hans yes it's unspecific and probably the case. (just find I didn't finish that sentence in answer :P)

Comment: @Hans the relevant link is https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class#copy.assign-example-3

Answer (score 0):

`c2 = c;`
Here we call **operator=** but class C doesn't have it (it is not generating in your case) then we call from base class B which has and it happens because we can cast C to B. That is why you see this message *B::operator=()*.

If we call *operator=* it doesn't mean that it will call all *operator=* from base classes. *operator=* is a method that doesn't have the same behavior as constructors or destructors. If you want to see copy for *A* class then add next:

```
B& operator=(const B& rhs) {
    A::operator=(rhs);
    std::cout << "B::operator=()" << std::endl;
    return *this;
}
```

If you don't explicitly call for *A::operator=* consequently it doesn't copy - the value **x** is always be same after initialization.

Comment: you're still calling `C::operator=(const C&)`, it's compiler generated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So basicly, operator= of C is called as a function inherited from B?

Comment: @Hans not true.

Comment: @appleapple Than I get confused again. From the perspective of C++ designer, the default behavior of operator= should be "copying everything in this object", if A is directly a part of C, I suppose its operator= should be called? Why isn't that happening?

Comment: @appleapple if it was generated then you would not see the message "B::operator=()" because method "C::operator=()" doesn't explicitly call "operator=()" for base classes. It is easy to check if you add a new integer field in C class and the field doesn't copy. pls see https://godbolt.org/z/j1s15e7Mh

Comment: @ichik well you can see at line 234 it definitely calls the `C` one...

Comment: @Hans yes, it is called "Name lookup".

Comment: @ichik and you print out `c` while set `c2`, I'm not surprised it's not changed.